# Promise.all with different return types

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, iterable

Promise.all() gets an iterable as input, is it possible for a promise.all to have different resolved type?

Example would be promise.all([promiseA, promiseB, promiseC], promiseA and promiseB returns void but promiseC returns boolean?

I tried and it seems is not possible, also I don't think an iterable can have different types but wanted to be sure. This is the error I see and this my code with TypeScript

```
PromiseC: Promise<boolean>;
PromiseA: Promise<void>;
PromiseB: Promise<void>;

const promises = [this.promiseA, this.promiseB];
if (!flag) {
   promises.push(this.promiseC); 
}
Promise.all(promises).then(() => { // do something}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean, different *resolve* types?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What exactly is it that you tried?

Comment: The results can be totally different things. For example it's pretty common to use Promise.all to call a number of api methods. In this case an iterable is just something that looks like a list.

Comment: `returns void` - whats that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use it with promises that return different types. `Promise.all(iterable)` as the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) states:

> returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed
>   as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no
>   promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that
>   rejects.

The resolved promise will be:

> ... fulfilled with an array containing all the values of the iterable passed as argument (also non-promise values).

Its return type is an Array, but because each element in a javascript array can contain any type, you can do exactly what you described. Below is an example, and from the console output you can see `undefined` is returned for two of the elements, as well as a `Number` and a `String` type.

```js
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(console.log("Doing work...then I return undefined like a function does"))
})
var p2 = undefined;
var p4 = Promise.resolve(true)
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("foo");
  }, 100);
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // Array contains multiple types.
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I updated the question with my code and error I am seeing, can it be because of TypeScript?

Comment: Not as familiar with TypeScript, but have you tried  Promise<any>? Or setting the return type of promises to array?

Comment: Or declaring the return type as  Promise < any[] > ?

Comment: @adamrights How to use this if we have more than 10 promises which return different types. TypeScript is giving error in that case because it accepts only upto 10 promises. Can you please tell me how to solve in that case?

Comment: break it up into two promise.all() in that case might be easiest (=